# SwitchCompat on RecyclerViewAdapter

Tags: java, android, switchcompat

I'm using only one `SwitchCompat` in my `RecyclerView` adapter. I need position of the clicked item on `RecyclerView` and it's working fine when I use `TextView` instead of `SwitchCompat`. But `SwitchCompat` have no response and no position returned.

Can anyone help me please? Here's the Adapter file.

```
public class Setting_Recycler_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Setting_Recycler_Adapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static final String TAG = "val" ;
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Channel_Model> channelsData;
    private Setting_Recycler_Adapter.ClickInterface click;

    public Setting_Recycler_Adapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<Channel_Model> data,Setting_Recycler_Adapter.ClickInterface clik) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.channelsData = data;
        this.click = clik;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        SwitchCompat mSwitchCompat;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mSwitchCompat = (SwitchCompat) itemView.findViewById(R.id.setting_channel_switch);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            click.posClicked((short)getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Setting_Recycler_Adapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.setting_recycler, parent, false);
        return new Setting_Recycler_Adapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final Setting_Recycler_Adapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mSwitchCompat.setText(channelsData.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.mSwitchCompat.setChecked(channelsData.get(position).isChannel());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return channelsData.size();
    }

    interface ClickInterface{void posClicked(short p);
}
```

And the `RecyclerView` layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:textDirection="rtl">

    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/setting_channel_switch"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:text="channel Name"
        android:textSize="17sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: define click interface object under view holder class may solve this

Comment: so where do you call `setOnCheckedChangeListener`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the `onSetCheckedChangeListener` along with `onTouchListener` for your `SwitchCompat`. So the implementation inside your `ViewHolder` class should look like the following.

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    SwitchCompat mSwitchCompat;
    Boolean isTouched = false;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mSwitchCompat = (SwitchCompat) itemView.findViewById(R.id.setting_channel_switch);

        mSwitchCompat.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                isTouched = true;
                return false;
            }
        });

        mSwitchCompat.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isTouched) {
                    isTouched = false;

                    if (isChecked) {
                        click.posClicked((short)getAdapterPosition());
                    } else {
                        // Do something on un-checking the SwitchCompat
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I think its needed. Because, OP has `holder.mSwitchCompat.setChecked(channelsData.get(position).isChannel());` inside the `onBindViewHolder` function which will call the `setOnCheckedChangeListener` which is un-necessary. We need to get the touch event to ensure that. Please correct me if I am wrong.